# Confirm alert displays but when clicking "cancel" it will perfom the delete query anyways

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, mysqli, backend

i'm currently creating a project which is a website for courses and right now i'm building the profile page of the user with the option of editing and seeing the information of the user, but i have a problem implementing the deleting account functionality.

There would be a delete button and a pop up for the user when clicking that button. The problem is that even if i click cancel it will perform the query, delete the user and send me to the index page, i don't know if it's a problem with redirecting or that i should echo the script with php instead of calling it from javascript, thanks in advance for any help you could provide.

```
<?php 

//selects current data of the logged user and display it

if (isset($_SESSION['id_user'])) {
    $id_session = $_SESSION['id_user'];


    $query = "SELECT id_user, first_name, last_name, username, email FROM users ";
    $query .= "WHERE id_user = ? ";

    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($con);
    $prepare = mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $query);

    if (!$prepare) {
        die('query failed' . mysqli_error($con));
    } else {

        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $id_session);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        $get_user_data = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_user_data)) {
            $id = $row['id_user'];
            $name = $row['first_name'];
            $last_name = $row['last_name'];
            $username = $row['username'];
            $email = $row['email'];

?>

<div class="profile-table">

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <td><?php echo $id; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <td><?php echo $name; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Last name</th>
        <td><?php echo $last_name; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Usernamee</th>
        <td><?php echo $username; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Email</th>
        <td><?php echo $email; ?></td>
    </tr>
</table>

</div>


<?php } } } ?>

<div class="cont-btn">

<div>
<a class="active-btn" href="profile.php?source=edit&id_u=<?php echo $id; ?>">Edit profile</a>   
</div>  

<div>   
<a class="active-btn del-btn" onClick="deleteConfirm()" href="profile.php?delete=<?php echo $id; ?>">delete account</a>
</div>

</div>




<?php 


if(isset($_GET['delete'])) {

$id_delete = $_GET['delete'];

$query = "DELETE FROM users WHERE id_user = ? ";
$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conexion);
$prepare = mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $query);

if(!$prepare) {
    die('Query failed' . mysqli_error($con));
} else {
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $id_delete);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    logout();

}
/* unset everything from session and relocates back to the index page

    function logout()
    {
            
    session_start(); 
    unset($_SESSION['id_user']);
    unset($_SESSION['name']);
    unset($_SESSION['lastname']);
    unset($_SESSION['username']);
    unset($_SESSION['email']);
    unset($_SESSION['role']);
    session_destroy();

    header("Location: ../index.php");

    } */




}

 ?>

 <script>
    function deleteConfirm() {
        confirm('Are you sure you want to delete your account?');
    }
 </script>
`
```

Comment: 1. `onClick="return deleteConfirm()"` 2.  `function deleteConfirm() {  return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete your account?'); }`

Comment: @mplungjan,thanks i'll try this